# Use tensorflow to approximate x=y

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to create a dummy tensorflow model to approximate the function x=y. It should be trivial, and enough with only one neuron, but the prediction is not really accurate. I would also expect the model to converge very fast, so I'm probably missing something in the coding.

The code I'm using:

```
    x_data = np.arange(32).reshape(-1,1)/32
    y_data = np.copy(x_data)
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=1)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation='linear')(inputs)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=output)
    model.summary()
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-1), loss='mae')
    model.fit(x=x_data,y=y_data,epochs=10000)
```

Comment: Try lowering the learning rate, e.g. to `1e-3` or even `3e-4`, and generate more data: `x_data = np.random.choice(32, size=10_000)`; lastly, if not working increase the `batch_size` too.

Comment: Change 'MAE' to 'MSE'. In only 100 epochs your code achives 1e-6 error, after 1000 epochs gets to zero (reported). I tried lr=1e-01

Comment: Indeed, your proposal of changing the loss function works @Pawel  thanks for your contribution. Do you have any idea why MAE does not converge? At the end of the day, these two losses are pretty much the same magnitude (only a power of 2 difference), and the function to approximate is really simple, so it should be straightforward.